# emscripten and boost library: how to compile existing project for webassembly?

Tags: c++, boost, emscripten

I have an existing project written on C++ that I would like to compile for webassembly using emscripten. The code calls boost library:

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <exception>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <boost/filesystem/fstream.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/exception.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/convenience.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/assign.hpp>
```

I have compiled the necessary parts of boost library using emscripten as static libraries and converted them from bc to a-files using emar. Now I'm trying to compile the project feeding the compiler with the precompiled libraries:
(part of Makefile)

```
C_OPTIONS= -O3 -DNDEBUG -g \
           /home/hiisi/workspace/boost_libs/program_options/build/emscripten-1.38.38/release/link-static/threading-multi/libs/cmdline.bc.a \
           /home/hiisi/workspace/boost_libs/program_options/build/emscripten-1.38.38/release/link-static/threading-multi/libs/config_file.bc.a \
           /home/hiisi/workspace/boost_libs/program_options/build/emscripten-1.38.38/release/link-static/threading-multi/libs/convert.bc.a \
           /home/hiisi/workspace/boost_libs/program_options/build/emscripten-1.38.38/release/link-static/threading-multi/libs/libboost_program_options.bc.a \
```

However make still complains on the very first occurrence of boost in the code:

```
main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'boost/program_options.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
shared:ERROR: compiler frontend failed to generate LLVM bitcode, halting
```

The question may sound little bit naive, but how do I correctly do this? The project compiles perfectly fine with g++, but not em++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All I had to do is to make sure that boost lib presents in emscripten include directory. In my case that was `emsdk/fastcomp/emscripten/system/include/` I made a symlink to system' boost library there and everything worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the include directories to use boost.

That would be an argument that look like this:

```
... -I/home/hiisi/workspace/boost_libs/include ...
```

Comment: em++  -ansi  -O3 -DNDEBUG -g -I /home/hiisi/workspace/boost_libs/program_options/build/emscripten-1.38.38/release/link-static/threading-multi/libs/ -I /usr/include/boost-  -I ../../../src/lib -o main.o -c ../../../src/main/main.cpp 

../../../src/main/main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'boost/program_options.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

shared:ERROR: compiler frontend failed to generate LLVM bitcode, halting
make: *** [../../makefile_common:19: main.o] Error 1

Comment: I have used -I to add the directory with all of my compiled libraries. The comment above shoes how the compilation string looks like now and the error it produces.

Comment: @HiisiT remove the spaces. it's `-I/directory` not `-I /directory`

Comment: @HiisiT also when adding include directories, you have to point to the directory which will contain `boost/header.h` not the compiled libraries.

Comment: Tried without spaces and it makes no difference. The correct boost directory with hpp and other headers files is linked. Still getting the same error: ```fatal error: 'boost/program_options.hpp' file not found``` The same make files compiles successfully with g++

Comment: @HiisiT It's not `/usr/include/boost`, but the directory you want to add is `/usr/include/`. The directory `/usr/include/boost` contain the header directly, but you want the directory that contain the `boost` folder so that `#include <boost/header.h>` works.

Comment: This is why my answer specify the last directory to be `..../include/` and not `..../include/boost`

Comment: it complains perfectly fine if i change em++ to g++

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196490/discussion-between-guillaume-racicot-and-hiisi-t).

Answer (score 0):

##### Use Emscripten Ports to simplify the compiling process:

https://emscripten.org/docs/compiling/Building-Projects.html#using-libraries
https://emscripten.org/docs/compiling/Building-Projects.html#emscripten-ports

---

**DEMO: C++ with boost in WASM and also show passing arrays between js/cpp**

using `example.cpp` as example:

`example.cpp:`

```
// example.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <emscripten/emscripten.h>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <vector>

namespace mp = boost::multiprecision;

extern "C" {

    EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
    int daysInWeek() {
        return 7;
    }

    EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
    int mypow(int a,int b) {
      mp::cpp_int x = mp::pow(mp::cpp_int(a), b);
      // std::cout << x << "\n";
      return (int) x;

    }
    EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
    int* createIntArray(int size) {
      std::vector<int> vec(size);
      // Populate the integer vec with some values
      for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
          vec[i] = i + 99; // Fill the array with values 1, 2, 3, ..., size
      }

      int* array = new int[vec.size()]; // Allocate memory for the array
      std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), array); // Copy vector elements to the array
      return array;
    }


    EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
    int powArr(int* a, int size) {
      mp::cpp_int x = mp::pow(mp::cpp_int(a[0]), a[1]);
      std::cout<<"Passed in array:[";
      for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
      {
        std::cout<< a[i];
        if(i<size-1) std::cout<<",";
      }
      std::cout<<"]\n";
      
      return (int) x;

    }

}
```

Generate `example.js` and `example.wasm`

```
emcc example.cpp -o example.js -sMODULARIZE -sEXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=ccall,cwrap -sUSE_BOOST_HEADERS=1 -s "EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=['_free','_malloc']"
```

if you don't want to use `ccall` or `cwrap` in js:

```
emcc example.cpp -o example.js -sMODULARIZE -sUSE_BOOST_HEADERS=1 -s "EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=['_free','_malloc']"
```

Test the wasm by running:

```
node testBoost.js
```

`testBoost.js:`

```
// testBoost.js
var factory = require('./example.js');

factory().then((wasmInstance) => {

  // simple function without paramenter
  console.log('daysInWeek:',wasmInstance._daysInWeek()); // values can be returned, etc.


  const res = wasmInstance._mypow(2,4); // direct calling works
  console.log('result 1: calling mypow,',res);

  // # using ccall
  // const res2 = wasmInstance.ccall("mypow",'number',['number','number'], [3,2]); // using ccall etc. also work
  // console.log('result 2',res2);

  // # using cwrap
  // const mypower = wasmInstance.cwrap('mypow', // name of C function
  // 'number', // return type
  // ['number', 'number']); // ar
  // const res3 = mypower(5,2);
  // console.log('result 3',res3);


  // testing getting array from cpp
  const cppOutputArrPointer = wasmInstance._createIntArray(5); 
  const js_output_array = new Uint32Array(wasmInstance.HEAP32.buffer, cppOutputArrPointer, 5);
  console.log('returned i32 array from cpp:',js_output_array);


  // testing passing array to cpp
  const TYPES = {
    i8: { array: Int8Array, heap: "HEAP8" },
    i16: { array: Int16Array, heap: "HEAP16" },
    i32: { array: Int32Array, heap: "HEAP32" },
    f32: { array: Float32Array, heap: "HEAPF32" },
    f64: { array: Float64Array, heap: "HEAPF64" },
    u8: { array: Uint8Array, heap: "HEAPU8" },
    u16: { array: Uint16Array, heap: "HEAPU16" },
    u32: { array: Uint32Array, heap: "HEAPU32" }
  };

  const jsInputArr = [3,4];
  const type = TYPES.i32;
  const typedArray = type.array.from(jsInputArr);
  // Allocate memory for the integer array
  const heapPointer = wasmInstance._malloc(typedArray.length * typedArray.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT);
  wasmInstance[type.heap].set(typedArray, heapPointer >> 2);

  // Call the WebAssembly function with the integer array
  const resArr = wasmInstance._powArr(heapPointer, jsInputArr.length);
  console.log("result of using powArr function", resArr);

  // Free the allocated memory
  wasmInstance._free(heapPointer);


});
```

I have put together a repo regarding various usage of cpp wasm:
https://github.com/cyavictor88/wasm-cpp